# Segmentation fault on linux when calling POCO c++ ServerSocket()

Tags: c++, linux, poco-libraries

On Fedora 29 with POCO C++ installed using

```
dnf install poco-devel
```

This code:

```
#include <Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h>

int main() {
    Poco::Net::ServerSocket svs(9980);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using this Makefile:

```
CC = g++
CPPFLAGS += -I/usr/include
CPPFLAGS += -I/usr/include/Poco
CFLAGS += -c
CFLAGS += -g
LDFLAGS += -g
LDLIBS += -lPocoFoundation 
LDLIBS += -lPocoUtil
LDLIBS += -lPocoNet
SOURCES = test.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE = test

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

install:
    @echo "Build complete!"
```

Gives the following in gdb

```
 Thread #1 [test] 8015 [core: 3] (Suspended : Signal :
 SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)    typeinfo name for
 Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl() at 0x4020c0   
    Poco::Net::SocketAddress::toString[abi:cxx11]() const at
 0x7ffff7ce2239     Poco::Net::SocketImpl::bind() at 0x7ffff7ce74c8 
    Poco::Net::ServerSocket::ServerSocket() at 0x7ffff7ce0e78       main() at
 test.cpp:6 0x4011c5
```

And in valgrind:

```
 ==8034== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
 ==8034==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x4020C0
 ==8034==    at 0x4020C0: ??? (in /path/to/test85-poco/test)
 ==8034==    by 0x4BCB238: Poco::Net::SocketAddress::toString[abi:cxx11]() const (in
 /usr/lib64/libPocoNet.so.60)
 ==8034==    by 0x4BD04C7: Poco::Net::SocketImpl::bind(Poco::Net::SocketAddress const&, bool,
 bool) (in /usr/lib64/libPocoNet.so.60)
 ==8034==    by 0x4BC9E77: Poco::Net::ServerSocket::ServerSocket(unsigned short, int) (in
 /usr/lib64/libPocoNet.so.60)
 ==8034==
```

Passing -v to g++ yields:

```
g++ -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/Poco -c -g -v test.cpp -o test.o
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada,go,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --enable-libmpx --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-cet --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.2.1 20181105 (Red Hat 8.2.1-5) (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' '/usr/include' '-I' '/usr/include/Poco' '-c' '-g' '-v' '-o' 'test.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/cc1plus -quiet -v -I /usr/include -I /usr/include/Poco -D_GNU_SOURCE test.cpp -quiet -dumpbase test.cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip test.o -g -version -o /tmp/ccDd0TCY.s
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 8.2.1 20181105 (Red Hat 8.2.1-5) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
    compiled by GNU C version 8.2.1 20181105 (Red Hat 8.2.1-5), GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.6-p2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.16.1-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/Poco
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../include/c++/8
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../include/c++/8/x86_64-redhat-linux
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../include/c++/8/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (GCC) version 8.2.1 20181105 (Red Hat 8.2.1-5) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
    compiled by GNU C version 8.2.1 20181105 (Red Hat 8.2.1-5), GMP version 6.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.6-p2, MPC version 1.1.0, isl version isl-0.16.1-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: a86aaae86aad006cc531272eca0396eb
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' '/usr/include' '-I' '/usr/include/Poco' '-c' '-g' '-v' '-o' 'test.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v -I /usr/include -I /usr/include/Poco --64 -o test.o /tmp/ccDd0TCY.s
GNU assembler version 2.31.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux) using BFD version version 2.31.1-13.fc29
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-I' '/usr/include' '-I' '/usr/include/Poco' '-c' '-g' '-v' '-o' 'test.o' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
g++ -g test.o -lPocoFoundation  -lPocoUtil -lPocoNet -o test
```

A more elaborate approach yields a similar result:

```
#include <Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string Address("192.168.0.11:9980");
    Poco::Net::SocketAddress addr(Address);

    if (addr.family() == static_cast<Poco::Net::IPAddress::Family>(Poco::Net::Impl::IPAddressImpl::IPv6)) {
        std::cout << "Addr: ipv6 " << std::endl;
    }
    else if (addr.family() == static_cast<Poco::Net::IPAddress::Family>(Poco::Net::Impl::IPAddressImpl::IPv4)) {
        std::cout << "Addr: ipv4 " << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Addr: something else (err)." << std::endl;
    }
    Poco::Net::ServerSocket svs(addr);
    return 0;
}
```

With this on the console:

```
 Addr: ipv4
```

gdb stack trace:

```
 Thread #1 [test] 7865 [core: 0] (Suspended : Signal :
 SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)        typeinfo name for
 Poco::Net::Impl::IPv6SocketAddressImpl() at 0x403100   
    Poco::Net::SocketAddress::toString[abi:cxx11]() const at
 0x7ffff7ce2239     Poco::Net::SocketImpl::bind() at 0x7ffff7ce74c8 
    Poco::Net::ServerSocket::ServerSocket() at 0x7ffff7ce0db7       main() at
 test.cpp:39 0x40236a
```

and valgrind report:

```
 ==7616== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
 ==7616==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x403100
 ==7616==    at 0x403100: ??? (in /path/to/test85-poco/test)
 ==7616==    by 0x4BCB238: Poco::Net::SocketAddress::toString[abi:cxx11]() const (in
 /usr/lib64/libPocoNet.so.60)
 ==7616==    by 0x4BD04C7: Poco::Net::SocketImpl::bind(Poco::Net::SocketAddress const&, bool,
 bool) (in /usr/lib64/libPocoNet.so.60)
 ==7616==    by 0x4BC9DB6: Poco::Net::ServerSocket::ServerSocket(Poco::Net::SocketAddress const&,
 int) (in /usr/lib64/libPocoNet.so.60)
 ==7616==    by 0x402375: main (test.cpp:38)
```

## Question:

How to create a ServerSocket on linux using POCO that executes without a segmentation fault?

Comment: Can you edit with the output of `g++ -v`?

Comment: Yes, so edited...

Comment: Separately also tried adding -std=c++11 and -std=c++14 and switched g++ to clang++ (v7.0.0) all without success

Comment: probalby your binaries have different options

Comment: I get this when trying to compile your more elaborate example:
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:8:100: error: ‘IPv6’ is not a member of ‘Poco::Net::Impl::IPAddressImpl’
 tic_cast<Poco::Net::IPAddress::Family>(Poco::Net::Impl::IPAddressImpl::IPv6)) {
                                                                        ^~~~

test.cpp:11:105: error: ‘IPv4’ is not a member of ‘Poco::Net::Impl::IPAddressImpl’
 tic_cast<Poco::Net::IPAddress::Family>(Poco::Net::Impl::IPAddressImpl::IPv4)) {
                                                                        ^

Answer (score 3):

Building POCO directly from source resolved the issue.  Used the following to build:

```
sudo dnf remove poco-devel
git clone https://github.com/pocoproject/poco
cd poco/build
cmake ..
make -j4
sudo make install
```

The POCO files are written to
/usr/local/include and
/usr/local/lib
so modified the makefile as follows:

```
CC = g++
CPPFLAGS += -I/usr/local/include
CPPFLAGS += -I/usr/local/include/Poco

CFLAGS += -c
CFLAGS += -g
LDFLAGS += -g
CFLAGS += -std=c++14
LDLIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
LDLIBS += -lPocoFoundation 
LDLIBS += -lPocoUtil
LDLIBS += -lPocoNet
LDLIBS += -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib
SOURCES = test.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE = test

all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

install:
    @echo "Build complete!"
```

ServerSocket on linux using POCO now executes without a segmentation fault.